# Reading line from file with double double quotes

Tags: perl, quotes, getline

What is the best way in perl to read line with double double quotes?
Example ,

```
            " This is ""an example"" of double double quotes"
```

I need to read this line and perform some manipulation and save it back onto a file .
Getline fails if i try to read this file .
Is there a better method to read this file and perform line to line manipulation ?

Comment: What do you mean, "Getline fails"? What's `Getline`, and how is it failing??? Please demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no *getline* in Perl. Are you possibly talking about `IO->getline()`?

Hmmm...

### File test.txt:

```
" This is ""an example"" of double double quotes"
```

### Perl program:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);
use autodie;

say "Using builtin Perl file operations.";
open my $fh, "<", "test.txt";
while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    chomp $line;
    say "The line is <$line>";
}
close $fh;

say "Using IO::File in order to use 'getline'.";
use IO::File;
my $io = IO::File->new;
$io->open("test.txt");
while ( my $line = $io->getline ) {
    chomp $line;
    say "The line is <$line>";
}
```

This prints:

```
$ ./test.pl
Using builtin Perl file operations.
The line is <" This is ""an example"" of double double quotes" >
Using IO::File in order to use 'getline'.
The line is <" This is ""an example"" of double double quotes" >
```

I am having absolutely no trouble reading lines with multiple quotes using either the builtin Pler file methods, or using `getline` from `IO::File`.

Can you be more specific in what you're experiencing? What are you attempting to do? What is your code?

Are you talking about Perl or Python?

Comment: It's probably a CSV file, in which case he should be using Text::CSV_XS, not this.

Comment: I thought so too, but the line he gave as an example isn't a line you see in a CVS file. Maybe this is a field? Who knows. I was hoping the OP would post more information.

Comment: please find the code segment that fail                                 smy $csvFile = new Text::CSV_XS({eol=>"\n", sep_char=>",", binary=>1, escape_char=> "\"", quote_char=> "\""});                            and the getline that fails : $Rec_ref = $csvFile -> getline($file)  or &zdie($MSG_PASSTHRU,"Unable to read line in $l_FileName :: $!\n");

Comment: I can't read that. Edit your question and put it in the question.